# Checking DB first before proceeding with sign up Keycloak

Tags: spring-boot, keycloak

**BACKGROUND**

I am currently building a microservice where I want to use Keycloak as my auth-server. I am not that familiar on Keycloak yet and I want to check first if the data provided by the user are all matched and existing on the DB before proceeding with the sign up. If the data are in the DB, then add the user.

**QUESTION**

1. How can I add a checking in DB first (This is done by calling a microservice) if all the data are matched and existing on the DB before adding the user?
2. If I can not do this or it is going to be hard, what alternatives can I do?
3. Also, in the future I am trying to add an OTP for a certain endpoint/s. So that before proceeding with a `post` request it will go to an OTP first, but there should be a login by username and password first before accessing the endpoint.